# batch update cassandra with lightweight transaction

Tags: cassandra

I am using cassandra 2.2.3 and want to make a batch update with two statements. Both using a lightweight transaction.

```
BEGIN BATCH
UPDATE account SET values['balance'] = 11 WHERE id = 1 IF values['balance'] = 10;
UPDATE account SET values['balance'] = 11 WHERE id = 2 IF values['balance'] = 10;
APPLY BATCH;
```

The batch returns following error:

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Batch with conditions cannot span multiple partitions".
```

I understand that it is not possible to make a batch on various PKs in the where clause because of the partitions, but why it is not possible to do a batch on the same PK? The problems are the IF statements, removing them, the batch is working.

So is there a solution to successfully execute such a batch update? Or any workaround?

EDIT:
This is my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE booking.account (
 id int PRIMARY KEY,
 values map<varchar, decimal>,
 timestampCreate timestamp,
 timestampUpdate timestamp
);
```

Comment: Can you show the table schema?

Comment: I add the schema to the post. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that it is not possible to make a batch on various PKs in
>   the where clause because of the partitions, but why it is not possible
>   to do a batch on the same PK?

You could make a batch on various PKs in the where clause, However this is not recommended (Please refer to [Cassandra: Batch loading without the Batch keyword](https://medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword-40f00e35e23e#.3cqm7eb2n)).

The problem here is conditional update (the if statement). Quote from [datastax cql reference](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html).

> In Cassandra 2.0.6 and later, you can batch conditional updates
>   introduced as lightweight transactions in Cassandra 2.0. Only updates
>   made to the same partition can be included in the batch because the
>   underlying Paxos implementation works at the granularity of the
>   partition. You can group updates that have conditions with those that
>   do not, but when a single statement in a batch uses a condition, the
>   entire batch is committed using a single Paxos proposal, as if all of
>   the conditions contained in the batch apply.

So do you really need batch statement? Read this [Using and misusing batches](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/useBatch.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. My aim using the batch was to do the same 'booking' on two accounts and either all of them execute successfully or none of them. I mean using a combination of CAS and batch would be a nice combination to do that.

Comment: Yes, I think there will be no other solution. This is a nice link for two-phase commits (in mongoDB) http://api.mongodb.org/wiki/current/two-phase%20commit.html I will try that. Thank you